# Mapping table for old Swiss municipality codes

Tags: data-request, europe, switzerland

This is Swiss related question:

I have two datasources, from 2000 and 2018, which I have to join using the Swiss municipality (BFS) codes. Within those 18 years difference, many municipalities fusionend and I am looking for a dataset to map old codes with new ones.

Does anyone know where I do find a mapping file/dataset?

- first dataset: https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/products/landscape/boundaries3D (2018)
- second dataset: https://www.pxweb.bfs.admin.ch/pxweb/de/px-x-4003000000_123/-/px-x-4003000000_123.px (2000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a dataset:

- https://www.agvchapp.bfs.admin.ch/de/mutated-communes/results?EntriesFrom=01.01.2000&EntriesTo=01.01.2019&Deleted=True (in German, French and Italian)